# Swagger Swashbuckle routes blocking

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.0

So I'm creating the workshop app from here:

([the link redirects to problematic part](https://github.com/csharpfritz/aspnetcore-app-workshop/blob/master/docs/1.%20Create%20BackEnd%20API%20project.md#testing-the-api-using-the-swashbuckle))

And i'm starting to configure swashbuckle in ASP.Net Core 3.0 app. UI itself works, but

I can't access my routes i defined in controllers and get them in URL because everything redirects to `https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html` despite the routes are defined in `https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

So i can't access for example: `https://localhost:5001/api/Speakers` or any other route because everything redirects to the `https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html` and the routes work fine without the swagger.

Only `https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json` works and the index

How to make it possible to make every url accessible?

My swashbuckle configuration is exactly the same as in the link

My packets: `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 5.0.0-rc4`
Also, the guide was for net.core 2.2 and i'm using 3.0 but everything before swagger works fine

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i solved it by just simply putting the methods `app.UseSwaggerUI`, `app.UseSwagger` and `app.Run` respectively at the end of `Startup.Configure` method.

That also solves another problem with executing HTTP requests in `/swagger/index.html` - it wasn't possible to execute actions like e.g. entering object to database via POST.